# Dell PERC H700 - 3x RAID 1?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc

The configurator on Dell's website only allows me to choose up to 2 RAID configurations (for example RAID1/RAID10). The R710 allows up to 6 HDD's though, so I could do 3 RAID 1 arrays. Does the PERC H700 controller support this? Should I simply select "No RAID array" in the configurator and then configure it myself when I get the server?

The reason is that I would want to do the following:

1. RAID 1 Array OS/Programs/TempDB/IIS/Web
2. RAID 1 Array SQL-LDF
3. RAID 1 Array SQL-MDF/Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Dell documentation](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/topic.aspx/global/products/pvaul/topics/en/us/raid_controller?c=us&l=en&cs=555), the H700 integrated supports 0,1,5,6,10,50,60 and the modular supports 0,1,5,6,10.  According to the [technical guidebook](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/perc-technical-guidebook.pdf), they both support a maximum number of 16 raid volumes.

Typically, when ordering Dell equipment, the configuration options do not necessarily reflect all possible configurations.  However, if it is not specified, your RAID will not come preconfigured.

Comment: I think the modular can also do 50 and 60, but it's limited to 4 drives (probably in the firmware). AFAIK it's LSI 2108 controller.

Comment: Thanks, @iconiK.  I actually have them in production but I usually use a single RAID1 or a RAID 1+0.

Comment: if you could flash the LSI firmware that would be great; coupled with expanders, it can RAID 240 drives.

Answer (score 0):

I have an R510 with the H700 controller. I don't know if you can order it in that configuration.

However, I do know that you can configure it that way once it arrives.